# Regular expression over the language C={a,b}

Tags: regular-language, nsregularexpression, automata, dfa, automata-theory

Good evening everyone,i'm getting stuck with the following regular expression,

I think there is a much easier approach to the expression than mine,

I had to writing down the regular expression and the dfa that from the alphabet {a,b} accepted all the strings that start and end with b and have an even number of a.

My attempt was going into cases, but the outcome, wasn't to great :

I tried something like this :
b b* (aba)* (aab)* (aa)* (aab)* (aba)*  b*b

But i think this is not complete.

Should i follow some general rule to achieve this task? Or i just need to practice regular expressions ?

Thanks,any tip or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DFA seems easier to make here, so we can start there and derive the regular expression from there.

We will need at least one, initial, state. This state cannot be accepting because the empty string does not start and end with `b`. We'll call this `q0`.

If we see an `a` in this state, we are looking at a string that does not start with `b`, so we cannot accept it no matter what comes next. We can represent this with a new, dead, state. We'll call this `q1`.

If we see a `b` in `q0`, we need a new state to represent the fact that we are well on the way to seeing a string that meets the criteria. Indeed, the string `b` starts and ends with a `b` and has an even number of `a` (zero is even); so this state must be accepting. Call this `q2`.

If we see an `a` in `q2` then we have an odd number of `a`s and did not last see a `b`, so we cannot accept the string. However, it's still possible to accept a string from this state by seeing an odd number of `a`s followed by at least one `b`. Call the state to represent this `q3`.

If we see a `b` in `q2`, we're in the same situation as before (even number of `a` and last saw a `b`, so we can accept). Stay in `q2`.

If in `q3` and we see an `a`, we now have an even number of `a` again and just need a `b`. Call this new state `q4`. If we see a `b`, we still need an `a` so we might as well stay in `q3`.

If in `q4` and we see an `a`, we again need more `a`s and can return to `q3`. If, on the other hand, we get a `b`, we can return to `q2` since the string is in our language.

The DFA looks like this:

```
 q     s    q'
--    --    --
q0     a    q1        q0: initial state
q0     b    q2        q1: dead state, did not begin with b
q1     a    q1        q2: accepting state, even #a and start/stop with b
q1     b    q2        q3: start with b, odd #a
q2     a    q3        q4: start with b, even #a, stop with a
q2     b    q2
q3     a    q4
q3     b    q3
q4     a    q3
q4     b    q2
```

To get the regular expression we can find regular expressions leading to each state, iteratively, and then take the union of regular expressions for accepting states. In this case, only `q2` is accepting so all we need is a regular expression for that state. We proceed iteratively, substituting at each stage.

```
round 0
(q0): e
(q1): (q0)a + (q1)(a+b)
(q2): (q0)b + (q2)b + (q4)b
(q3): (q2)a + (q3)b + (q4)a
(q4): (q3)a

round 1
(q0): e
(q1): a + (q1)(a+b) = a(a+b)*
(q2): b + (q2)b + (q4)b = (b+(q4)b)b*
(q3): (q2)a + (q3)b + (q4)a = ((q2)+(q4))ab*
(q4): (q3)a

round 2
(q0): e
(q1): a(a+b)*
(q2): (b+(q3)ab)b*
(q3): ((q2)+(q3)a)ab* = (q2)ab* + (q3)aab* = (q2)ab*(aab*)*
(q4): (q3)a

round3:
(q0): e
(q1): a(a+b)*
(q2): (b+(q3)ab)b*
(q3): (b+(q3)ab)b*ab*(aab*)* = bb*ab*(aab*)*+(q3)abb*ab*(aab*)* = bb*ab*(aab*)*(abb*ab*(aab*)*)*
(q4): (q3)a

round4:
(q0): e
(q1): a(a+b)*
(q2): (b+bb*ab*(aab*)*(abb*ab*(aab*)*)*ab)b*
(q3): bb*ab*(aab*)*(abb*ab*(aab*)*)*
(q4): bb*ab*(aab*)*(abb*ab*(aab*)*)*a
```

Therefore, a regular expression is this:

```
r = (b+bb*ab*(aab*)*(abb*ab*(aab*)*)*ab)b*
  = bb* + bb*ab*(aab*)*(abb*ab*(aab*)*)*abb*
```

1. The `bb*` part encodes the fact that any string of `b` is a string in the language.
2. the other part begins and ends with `bb*` which encodes the fact that any string must begin and end with `b`
3. The outermost `a`s encode the fact that any string in the language with `a` must have both a first and a last `a`
4. The `aab*` parts allow there to be contiguous pairs of `a`
5. The `abb*ab*` part allow allows there to be non-contiguous pairs of `a`

As a final note, the rules for replacing expressions as above are the following:

```
A: r       r is an expression
B: As      s is an expression
=
A: r
B: rs


A: r + As  r, s are expressions
=
A = rs*
```

Comment: Yikes, that's a complicated regex for this. From the description of the problem `bb*(ab*a|b)*bb*` should do it. If you want to accept the string `"b"`, then add `b|` to the front of the expression.

Comment: @Welbog At what point between 17 symbols and 38 symbols does the regular expression go from being simple to complicated? At least this one has the benefit of being derived using a dumb mechanical process. It is Monday morning, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Good evening ! check it out

**b(aa)*b**

this results in generation of strings having starting and end on **b**

and containing even clumps of **a** if any i-e 
produce **a** in multiple of 2  i-e  even number